# Finding time differences between multiple times

Tags: python, time, python-datetime

I'm creating an application that looks at the sunrise and sunset to see what part of a duration is during the day/night in hours. Currently, I have two python datetime objects that represent the starting and ending times of the duration, and I already have the times of the sunset and sunrise in datetime objects. I know my code is very messy, but I'll fix it when I know what I'm dealing with in my issue with this.

My code so far:

```
if(datetime_object_1 <= datetime_object_2 <= sunrise <= sunset):
    return (0,differencehours(datetime_object_1, datetime_object_2))
elif(datetime_object_1 <= sunrise <= datetime_object_2 <= sunset):
    return (differencehours(datetime_object_2, sunrise), differencehours(datetime_object_1, sunrise))
elif(sunrise <= datetime_object_1 <= datetime_object_2 <= sunset):
    return (differencehours(datetime_object_1, datetime_object_2),0)
elif(sunrise <= datetime_object_1 <= sunset <= datetime_object_2):
    return (differencehours(datetime_object_1, sunset), differencehours(datetime_object_2, sunset))
elif(sunrise <= sunset <= datetime_object_1 <= datetime_object_2):
    return (0,differencehours(datetime_object_1, datetime_object_2))
else:
    return (None, None)

def difference(datetime_str_1, datetime_str_2):
    if(datetime_object_1 > datetime_object_2):
        datetime_object_1_replace = datetime_object_1
        datetime_object_2_replace = datetime_object_2
        datetime_object_2 = datetime_object_1_replace
        datetime_object_1 = datetime_object_2_replace
    difference = datetime_object_2 - datetime_object_1
    return difference

def differencehours(datetime_str_1, datetime_str_2):
    return (difference(datetime_str_1, datetime_str_2).total_seconds / 3600.0)
```

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Please elaborate on it

Comment: Ever single time I run this code, no matter if the duration is in the middle of the night, it still gives me that the whole duration in in the day.

Comment: See the answer below and try and incorporate that idea. A side note: your code is what a bad code looks like :)

Comment: Can you provide a runnable test code snippet, with some hardcoded datetimes, that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 Well, thanks for reminding me. :) I haven't used python in a very long time, and I'm sometimes afraid to delete what's working!

Comment: can sunrise object ever be greater than sunset object?

Comment: Just looked at your code again... first you implement the difference function yourself, and you really don't need to. Second, you pass datetime_str_1 and datetime_str_2 into it, but calculated on datetime_object_1 and datetime_object_2 instead. This already sets a couple of red flags here.

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says, `Simple is better than complex.`

You can simplify your code drastically if you use a simple logic for just finding night/day hours and then subtracting it from total working hours to get day/night respectively.

You don't need so many `if else`.

Following code would do the trick :

```
from datetime import datetime

sunrise_time = datetime(2020, 3, 22, 5, 0, 0, 0)  # 5 am
sunset_time = datetime(2020, 3, 22, 18, 0, 0, 0)  # 6 pm

duration_start = datetime(2020, 3, 22, 15, 0, 0, 0)
duration_end = datetime(2020, 3, 22, 17, 0, 0, 0)


def difference_in_seconds(time1, time2):
    return (time1 - time2).total_seconds()


def find_day_night_hours_duration(d_start, d_end, sunrise, sunset) -> (float, float):
    working_seconds = (d_end - d_start).total_seconds()

    night_working_seconds = 0

    if d_start < sunrise:
        # they started before sunrise, add it to night hours
        night_working_seconds = difference_in_seconds(sunrise, d_start)

    if sunset < d_end:
        # means, they worked after sunset
        night_working_seconds += difference_in_seconds(d_end, sunset)
    if night_working_seconds > working_seconds:
        # all working hours are night hours
        return 0, working_seconds / 3600

    return (working_seconds - night_working_seconds) / 3600, (night_working_seconds) / 3600


print(find_day_night_hours_duration(duration_start, duration_end, sunrise_time, sunset_time))
```

Output :

```
(2.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: Wow! I just realized that I could have done this is such an easier way! Thanks for opening my eyes.

Comment: if this solves your problem,please consider it marking as Accepted

Comment: For some reason, for hours well into the night I get negative day hours and more than the actual amount of night hours. If I add it up, the total is correct though. I would just correct this through making a conditional to see if the duration is completely in the night or day, right?

Comment: can you share your input for which the output is in negative hours.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the time difference between datetime objects in python is really, really simple. As simple as `delta = datetime1 - datetime2`. To get it in seconds use `delta.total_seconds()` Demo:

```
import time, datetime
a = datetime.datetime.now()
time.sleep(1.5)
b = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = b - a
print(delta.total_seconds())
```

Comment: What I'm really asking for is what I've done wrong in my logic, since I'm using .total_seconds() in my "difference" function. Thanks!

Comment: @TheCoolKid, indeed you do, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @TheCoolKid - note - while you DO use total_seconds(), you do some strange stuff to calculate the difference. You pass datetime_str_1 and datetime_str_2 which aren't strings, but datetime-s, but instead of just subtracting them, you mess around with some other objects of unknown origin!